# do list matching in and print matched string

Tags: r

i have one list which looks like this :-

```
 [1] "Obec:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [2] "Část obce:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                                                                         
 [3] "Parcela a katastrální území:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t216/1, k.ú. Dolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t216/1, k.ú. Dolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                               
 [4] "Čísla popisná nebo evidenční:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                                                                                                                 
 [5] "Typ:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tbudova s číslem popisným\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                                                                                                                   
 [6] "Způsob využití:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tobjekt k bydlení\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
```

now i want to do string matching in R which will do like :-
if string have "Způsob využití:" it should print entire line .

desired output is :-

```
"Způsob využití:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tobjekt k bydlení\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
```

after that i will remove \n\r\t so no problem regarding same.

edit

`dput(col_names) c("Obec:DoleniceDolenice", "Cást obce:DoleniceDolenice", "Parcela a katastrální území:216/1, k.ú. Dolenice216/1, k.ú. Dolenice", "Císla popisná nebo evidencní:1", "Typ:budova s císlem popisným", "Zpusob využití:objekt k bydlení", "Datum dokoncení:Druh svislé nosné konstrukce:", "Pocet bytu:0Pripojení na vodovod:", "Zastavená plocha [m2]:Pripojení na kanalizacní sít:", "Obestavený prostor [m3]:Pripojení na rozvod plynu:", "Podlahová plocha [m2]:Zpusob vytápení:")`

Comment: You can use `grep` in this scenario. If your string vector is called `my_strings` then you can try `grep("Způsob využití:", my_strings, value = TRUE)`

Comment: i tried, but getting output as :- character(0)

Comment: My example below, taking your exact strings gives this exact result. You can try copy / pasting and confirming this.

Comment: i am sorry my mistake in question. i am having list not string.

Comment: The console output does not confirm your claim that this is a list. Use dput to present unambiguous version of R objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` in this scenario:

```r
gsub('\n|\r|\t', '', grep("Způsob využití:", my_strings, value = TRUE))
#> [1] "Zpusob využití:objekt k bydlení"
```

---

**Data in reproducible format**

```r
my_strings <- c("Obec:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",                                                                                                                                                                                
"Část obce:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",                                                                                         
"Parcela a katastrální území:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t216/1, k.ú. Dolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t216/1, k.ú. Dolenice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",                                               
"Čísla popisná nebo evidenční:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",                                                                                                                                 
"Typ:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tbudova s číslem popisným\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",                                                                                                                                   
"Způsob využití:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tobjekt k bydlení\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t")
```

Comment: this works like butter , but i am having list not string . i am sorry again :(

Comment: @walle_eva if you have a list called `my_strings` then just replace `my_strings` in the above code with  `unlist(my_strings)`. If this doesn't work, please post a reproducible example (such as the output of `dput(my_strings)` so that we can help you better.

Comment: ok i will try it out

Comment: `col_names <- stringr::str_remove_all(col_name, "\\\t|\\\n|\\\r")
class(col_names)
gsub('\n|\r|\t', '', grep("Způsob využití:", col_names, value = TRUE))
head(col_names)
unlisted <- unlist(col_names)
gsub('\n|\r|\t', '', grep("Způsob využití:", unlisted, value = TRUE))
class(unlisted)
head(unlisted)
`

Comment: > class(unlisted)
[1] "character"

Comment: any idea? what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @walle_eva you need edit your question (not post in the comments) with a reproducible example. Type `dput(col_names)` into your console, and copy/paste the result into your question so we could help. I'm sure your problem is easy to fix, but we need to see _exactly_ what you are working with. We can't really help until you have done this.  Your question has been closed due to others not being able to understand it for this reason.

Comment: @walle_eva please edit your question - don't post code in the comments. Click the little label that says `edit` under your question and put this information in there.

Comment: I am sorry , done i edited it